# Problema con matrices dinámicas

Tags: c, array, punteros, matrices

estoy haciendo un programa para trabajar con matrices dinámicas pero estoy teniendo problemas con el código, pues da igual el valor que le de a los elementos de la matriz, siempre me aparece el número -13344. Alguien podría ayudarme o decirme qué estoy haciendo mal, por favor? Muchas gracias a todos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
//definimos el tipo de dato Matriz 
typedef struct{
    int i;
    int j;
    int *datos;
}Matriz;

Matriz *m;
int k=0;
int l=0;
int fil, col;


//pedimos los datos al usuario y los escaneamos
printf("Número de filas:");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d",&fil);
printf("Número de columnas:");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d", &col);
m = (Matriz*)malloc(sizeof(Matriz));
m->i=fil;
m->j=col;
m->datos = (int*)malloc(m->i*m->j*sizeof(int*));
for(k = 0 ; k<fil; k++){
    for(l=0; l<col; l++){
        printf("Elemento %d%d", k, l);
        fflush(stdout);
        //scanf("%d",&(m[k*col +l]));
        scanf("%d",&(m[k*col +l]));
    }
}
//imprimimos la matriz
for(k = 0; k < fil; k++){
    printf("\n");
for(l = 0; l < col; l++){
   printf("%d ", *(m + k*col + l));

 }
}

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Echar un vistazo a las [listas genéricas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como diria *Jack el Destripador*, **vamos por partes**:

```
m->datos = (int *)malloc(m->i * m->j * sizeof( int * ) );
```

Eso es incorrecto. Estas reservando memória para **punteros a enteros**, **NO para enteros**.
La forma correcta sería:

```
m->datos = (int *)malloc( m->i * m->j * sizeof( int ) );
```

En la síguiente línea

```
scanf("%d",&(m[k*col +l]));
```

Estas solicitando que el dato se guarde en una dirección incorrecta, puesto que has tomado como base el puntero a la matriz `m`, en lugar del puntero a los datos, que es `m->datos`. Eso mismo sucede con `printf("%d ", *(m + k*col + l));` Ese es el fallo principal de tu código.
De hecho, lo raro es que no te de ningún error al ejecutarlo.

Por último,

```
for( k = 0 ; k < fil; k++){
  for( l = 0; l < col; l++){
    ...
  }
}
```

Eso es innecesario. Piensa que los elementos en memoria están **uno a continuación de otro**. Es más fácil hacerlo jugando con divisiones y restos de divisiones.

Aplicando mis consejos, tu código, reescrito:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Matrix {
  int x;
  int y;
  int data[0]; /* Para facilitarnos la vida. */
};

int main( void ) {
  struct Matrix *m;
  int x, y;
  int total;
  int actual;

  fflush( stdin );
  printf( "Filas: " );
  scanf( "%d", &y );
  printf( "Columnas: " );
  scanf( "%d", &x );

  total = x * y;
  m = (struct Matrix *)malloc( sizeof( struct Matrix ) + ( sizeof( int ) * total ) );

  /* Pedimos los valores. */
  for( actual = 0; actual < total; ++actual ) {
    printf( "Valor de (%d, %d): ", actual / y, actual % y );
    scanf( "%d", &(m->data)[actual] );
  }

  /* Los imprimimos. */
  for( actual = 0; actual < total; ++actual ) {
    printf( "Valor de (%d, %d): %d\n", actual / y, actual % y, (m->data)[actual] );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Una mejora en el código (que no es ni mucho menos indispensable) es cambiar los bucles que piden y recorren los valores incrementando la variable `actual` por dos bucles anidados (incrementando `x` y `y` y en el bucle interior únicamente `actual`). Así se evita obtener el resultado para la misma división una y otra vez durante `y` filas, así como una operación de módulo. Te llevas mi +1 :) PD: Yo, personalmente, haría una matriz bidimensional: una matriz de dimensión `i` de punteros a una matriz de dimensión `j` de enteros. Así el acceso sería `m->data[i][j]`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, de verdad, me has ayudado muchísimo!

Comment: Como tu dices es como lo tenía originalmente el usuario. Lo he cambiado para **iluminarlo** con otros posibles caminos (seguramente que así como lo he puesto no lo enseñan en la Uni). En mi caso, siempre que puedo utilizo `array[0]`. Me gusta como queda, y permite asignar 1 solo bloque de memória (matriz + datos), en lugar de 2 (matriz **y** datos). Gracias por el voto ;-)

Comment: Por favor @sqldud , si consideras que ha sido de utilidad la respuesta de Trauma deberías darle un voto y, si resuelve tu consulta, marcarla como respuesta correcta.

Comment: Si, gracias @OscarGarcia, ya lo he hecho :)